# jqxgrid grid filter dialog not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid

I have problem with columns filter dialog not showing in IE

it works fine in all other browsers

I have had already great trouble with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

in IE

I suspect something related to the order of these definitions

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/demos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqwidgets/jqxvalidator.js"></script>
```

thanks to jqwidgets team for great work :)

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this sample: [jQWidgets Grid Filtering](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/filtering.htm?arctic). Works fine with IE on my side. According to me, the `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be always used in your web pages.

Answer (score 0):

thanks

the problem is that the grid is within window jqxWindow

i just defined div as in the example without embedding it within other divs